# Iframe doesnt resize on iphone

Tags: html, iphone, iframe

I have included a javascript app for building plates into a wordpress website, everything looks ok on most of the browsers and some of the android cell phone, but only a part of the app is shown on iphone, is there a way to force iphone browser to resize the iframe so the app can be usable from iphones too.

P.S: If you look at the link from an iphone browser, you will know what i actually mean.

http://www.my-plates.co.uk/show-number-plates-builder/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of a percentage width and `max-width`:

```
#yourIFrame {
    width: 100%; /* or whatever width you want it to be on the iPhone */
    max-width: 500px; /* or whatever its original width was */
}
```

You could also use media queries:

```
@media (max-width: 500px) { /* or the minimum width in order to trigger the resizing */
    #yourIFrame {
        width: 100%; /* or any other width, can be in px too */
    }
}
```